# How to get an object from a Json file using toJson and fromJson

Tags: android, json

I am very new to android and am practising in adding class object to file using toJson and fromJson. I managed to write my object to the txt file but I don't know how to get it back from there using fromJson. All code is below:
initialization inside onCreate method:

```
cookie1.income=10;
    cookie1.cookieNumber=1;
    writeObject(cookie1);
```

-

```
public void writeObject(cookie cookie1){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String s = gson.toJson(cookie1);
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput("file.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

-

```
public class cookie{
long cookieNumber;
long income;
}
```

here is what I have in my txt file

```
{"coockieNumber":1,"income":10}
```

Comment: Read file by InputStream and then pass string it to Gson to get your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to read content of the file.

```
 private String readFile() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("file.txt");

        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fis.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }

        fis.close();
        return temp;
}
```

Then,

```
String data = null;

    try{

    data = readFile();

    } catch(IOException e) {}
```

`data` conatins your contents of the file. Now use `Gson`

```
    if(data != null) {
    cookie obj = new Gson().fromJson(data, cookie.class);
}
```